# fopen (example.txt", "a+" )is not writing on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, fopen

I am making a plugin for a web page in wordpress,
I need to debug a block of code, for this I must send messages to a debug file

the way i make the call is as follows

```
        $dbug = fopen("devDebug.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($dbug, "Ingreso email");
        fclose($dbug);
```

The problem is that the file is not created. It also doesn't throw an error or crash

Comment: Why not use `error_log`?

Comment: Did you check the php/apache error log on disk

Comment: @user3783243 i also use write_log works in some file, but this in particular didnt.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that is a file in wordpress directory ?

Comment: @Motias `write_log` is not a native PHP function, did you create it? `error_log` is native to PHP and should write to system path you have set up.

Comment: wirte_log is defined in wordpress but dont work all time, where i can define de path to error_log ?

Comment: @Motias See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel